# Limit, offset and starting ID in Symfony 6 entity repositories

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an entity and repository to fetch details:

```
$subscriptions = $userSubscriptionRepo->findBy(
    ['isDeleted' => false , 'disabled' => false],
    null,
    $this->paginationLimit, //5
    0
);
```

On initial load, this will retrieve the first 5 items within the DB. But in our product, new subscriptions are happening all the time and my hope is to create lazy loading of subscriptions and that will be handled by another call.

The problem is that if more items are added, the limit will retrieve the next five, but shifted by the amount added (could be 2 - 5). So now I have an issue where the next five could be the same ones or well into the list  +5 which wont be accurate representation. Is there a condition within findBy that allows me to do a call that has something similar to "start from ID" that then allows the limit + offset to start from there?

Example:

```
$subscriptions = $userSubscriptionRepo->findBy(
    ['isDeleted' => false , 'disabled' => false],
    null,
    $this->paginationLimit, //5
    0,
    ['startFromID' = '5'] // so that it ensures no matter how many is added, it will start from this id
);
```

Comment: I think I see what you mean on a live site, maybe a nice problem to have if you're getting that many subs. Anyways, could you not just orderBy (second param of findBy) ASC, meaning old first to newest last? So all new entries get added to the end, so when browsing you shouldn't see the jump unless browsing the end pages of course..

Comment: That's a great solution - also out of curiosity is it possible to do something similar to what I asked?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is creating a custom repository method that still can use findBy, but getting the newest id then setting a redirect with an added url query param (eg. startFrom). The method can also take in startFrom param (can be null also). You can filter the results to chop off anything before that id. Hard to explain but hopefully you get the idea..

Comment: What you are looking for is generally called "cursor pagination"

Comment: Are there ways of creating this? Glad there is a name I can reference